# If action name found then call action, if not call a default action in MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

this is my current routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{action}/{id}",                                        // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "MarketingSite", action = "index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

so whenever I visit domain.com/test

This would invoke the test action in the controller called MarketingSite.

What I want to achieve is when I visit domain.com/load-from-db and since I don't have an action called load-from-db, I want to direct the request to a specific action and load-from-db becomes the parameter for that action.  In that action, i'm going to read something from the database based on the parameter and then return a view.  If I specify an action that exist, then it would just call that action.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First note - the routing engine will apply the routes in the order you list them, checking each, and continuing if it cannot match. You currently have the "default" route setup as a catch-all - if is doesn't find a controller it uses "MarketingSite", if there is no action it uses "index". If I am understanding your problem, you don't want an "Index" action at all, you want to call another action, and pass the query to that.

You could try:

```
//Look for a matching action        
routes.MapRoute(
                    "MatchAction", // Route name
                    "{action}/{id}",
                     new { controller = "MarketingSite", id = UrlParameter.Optional}                                    
                );

//With a single segment, pass that to a specific action as a parameter.
routes.MapRoute(
                    "load-from-db",  // Route name
                    "{load-from-db}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "MarketingSite", action = "MyAction"}
                );

//With no segments (ex. domain.com/) use the Index on MarketingSite as default.
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default", // Route name
                    "", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "MarketingSite", action = "Index"}
                );
```

**However**, these routes might not accomplish exactly what you are looking for - getting your routes mapped in MVC can be a bit tricky. You should check this [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814) out, and design your routes accordingly.

Hope that helps, 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Override the `HandleUnknownAction` method on the `MarketingSite` controller:

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName) {
   // TODO: check for actionName in database
}
```